# How do I open an associated file so that it opens the associated program with admin rights (on demand)?

Tags: windows-10

I can run some programs with admin rights but right-clicking them and then selecting "Run as Administrator".

I would like to know if there is a built-in way to make Windows 10 open an associated program with admin rights, too.

But only on demand, not always.

Why?

VB6 project files (.vbp) are associated with "VB6.exe" on my computer.

Double-clicking a .vbp file opens VB6.exe and loads this .vbp file.

When I want to run a VB6 project as an admin, I have to first right-click VB6.exe, select "Run as Admin".
Then I have to use the File -> Open dialog to search for this vbp file so that I can then open it.

This is time-taking if you have to do it open.

If I right-click a vbp file, there is no "Run as Admin" option, so I currently see no way to do what I want.

Is there a built-in way that I have not found / noticed yet?

Thank you!

Comment: If this is always the case, you can right-click VB6.exe, set its compatibility options to always run as administrator, now it will work.

Comment: [You should be able to accomplish this with a manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636742/how-to-modify-an-exe-file-to-force-it-to-start-as-administrator-without-source-c),  This seems more like a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @LPChip Thank you, but I don't want to always run it as an admin. Only in some cases.